# Unexpected string from Chrome storage set

Tags: javascript, local-storage, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to **set** in localStorage after checking if the key already exists, but I'm getting this error. Anyone know what is happening and how can I solve it?

```
chrome.storage.sync.get($div.attr('id'),function(items){
    var lastError = chrome.runtime.lastError;
    if (lastError) console.log($div.attr('id')+" does not exist.\n", lastError);
    else chrome.storage.sync.set({$div.attr('id'):$div.html()}, function(){}); //I'm having the error from this line
});
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

**Edit:**
Apparently this has something to do with the attr('id')
because I created a variable and then the problem was gone. Thank you anyway.
This is working:

```
var myobj = {}, key = $div.attr('id');
myobj[key] = $div.html();
chrome.storage.sync.get(key,function(items){
    var lastError = chrome.runtime.lastError;
    if (lastError) console.log(key+" does not exist.\n", lastError);
    else chrome.storage.sync.set(myobj, function(){}); //The error is gone
});
```

Comment: Just a tiny nit for your updated snippet (sorry if I'm stating the obvious): you might want to move your var to the very top and use it in the 2 places where you still have $div.attr('id').

Comment: Note on the question, the edited version reported to be working will not error, but it's storing the data with the literal key "key", not the id attribute gotten from the div.

Comment: Yes both are probably right, I'll update with my latest code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't with `attr` itself, but in the way you're trying to dynamically set a key on a new object literal using it:

```
{$div.attr('id'):$div.html()}
```

You can't create an object literal in this way.  Keys in the creation of an object literal must be string or numeric literals.

To attach a dynamic key to an object you'd rather do something like this:

```
else {
  var obj = {}, key = $div.attr('id');
  obj[key] = $div.html();
  chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function(){});
}
```